# Fetch data from other site (php & GET)

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from a site and be able to manipulate it to display it on my own site.
The site contains a **table** with **ticks** and is updated every few hours.
Here's an example: http://www.astynomia.gr/traffic-athens.php

This data is there for everyone to use, and I will mention them on my own site just to be sure.

I've read something about php's cURL but I have no idea if this is the way to go.
Any pointers/tutorials, or code anyone could provide so I can start somewhere would be very helpful. 
Also any pointers on how I can get informed as soon as the site is updated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829760/how-to-parse-a-html-and-store-into-database-using-curl-in-php-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to crawl the page, use something like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for PHP. That'll server your purpose.

Comment: after a little studying i figured it out, worked great, thanx

Answer (score 1):

First, your web host/localhost should have the php_curl extension enabled.

To start with, you should read a bit [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). If you want to jump in directly, there is a simple function here [Why I can't get website content using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697184/why-i-cant-get-website-content-using-curl). You just have to change the value of the variables  $url,$timeout

Lastly, to get the updated data every 2hrs you will have to run the script as a cronjob. Please refer to this post
[PHP - good cronjob/crontab/cron tutorial or book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959099/php-good-cronjob-crontab-cron-tutorial-or-book)

Comment: to enable the curl i go wamp/php/phpextentions and tick the curl right? thats all?   
also, what would be preferable? @bibhas crawling solution or cUrl?

Comment: to enable the curl i go wamp/php/phpextentions and tick the curl right? - yes, don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: Try to use Simple HTML DOM Parser first for your requirements.  http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/3123-Scrape-Site-Content-with-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser-in-PHP